# using CDO to extract dataset only for a specific region

Tags: dataset, extract, cdo-climate

I want to use 'cdo' to extract data from a precipitation NetCDF dataset using another NetCDF over South America.
I have tried multiple procedures, but I always get some error (such as grid size not same, Unsupported generic co-ordinates, etc).

The codes I have tried:

```
cdo mul chirps_2000-2015_annual_SA.nc Extract feature.nc output.nc
# Got grid error

cdo -f nc4 setctomiss,0 -gtc,0 -remapcon,r1440x720 Chirps_2000-2015_annual_SA.nc CHIRPS_era5_pev_2000-2015_annual_SA_masked.nc
# Got unsupported generic error
```

Comment: If the grid is missing then you might find data slicing in NCO more helpful, the links to the files are now dead so I removed the last sentence referring to the dead link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you could make/find more elegant solution, but I just combined `Python` and shell executable `cdo` to fulfill the task (calling subprocess can be considered as a bad habit sometimes/somewhere).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import subprocess
# -------------------------------------------------
def nc_varget(filein,varname):
    ncin=Dataset(filein);
    vardata=ncin.variables[varname][:];
    ncin.close()
    return vardata
# -------------------------------------------------
gridfile='extract_feature.nc'
inputfile='precipitation_2000-2015_annual_SA.nc'
outputfile='selected_region.nc'
# -------------------------------------------------
# Detect the start/end based on gridfile:
poutlon=nc_varget(gridfile,'lon')
poutlat=nc_varget(gridfile,'lat')

pinlon=nc_varget(inputfile,'lon')
pinlat=nc_varget(inputfile,'lat')

kkx=np.where((pinlon>=np.min(poutlon)) & (pinlon<=np.max(poutlon)))
kky=np.where((pinlat>=np.min(poutlat)) & (pinlat<=np.max(poutlat)))
# -------------------------------------------------
# -------------------------------------------------
commandstr='cdo selindexbox,'+str(np.min(kkx))+','+str(np.max(kkx))+','+str(np.min(kky))+','+str(np.max(kky))+' '+inputfile+' '+outputfile
subprocess.call(commandstr,shell=True)
```

The problem in your data is that the file "precipitation_2000-2015_annual_SA.nc" does not specify the grid at the moment - variables lon, lat are generic and hence the grid is generic. Otherwise you could use other operators instead of `selindexbox`. File `extract_feature.nc` are more closer to the standard as the variables lon, lat have also the name and unit attributes.